# How to link Dynpro screen elements to program variables?

Tags: controls, abap, dynpro

I am trying to use the elements I made in Screen Painter in my source code but I am not quite sure how to link them. Can you provide steps how I can link my elements in Screen Painter with ABAP variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection is established via the name.

If you declare a variable in your report like this:

```
DATA foo TYPE c.
```

Then you can view it on your screen by adding a field called `foo`.

A useful feature of the screen painter is choosing dictionary/program fields. You can access it by pressing `F6`.

Comment: It's actually a good idea to use DDIC elements (e. g. grouped in a 'screen structure') for screens instead of ABAP types. This will provide access to the labels, documentation text and value help defined in the DDIC.

Answer (score 2):

The reference is made by the name of **global** variables.

You may - as already mentioned - use a `DATA matnr TYPE MATNR.` to create a global variable `matnr`.

If you use DDIC-structures or tables you may also define them as

```
TABLES: MARA.
```

In screen painter you can reference the fields of the table/structure `MARA`.
(You can replace `MARA` with any table/structure).

Depending on the complexity of your program you may define your own structure, just as a interface between the report code and the screen-painter.

Answer (score 0):

The variables used in screen painter should be declared in a TOP in order to be accessed from the includes in the program.

For example, in my screen I request for a Business Partner name and map it to GT_NAME. GT_NAME should be declared in the TOP with something like the code below:

```
DATA: GT_NAME type bu_first.
```

That automatically creates the link between the global variables and the input parameters in the screen.